# How to declare wsdlfilelocation in Spring boot webservice project?

Tags: web-services, spring-boot, soap, wsdl, pom.xml

I am developing a spring boot application which contains wsdl file, here is my declaraion in pom.xml :

```
 <wsdlUrls>
    <wsdlUrl>src/main/resources/logging_service.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
 </wsdlUrls>
```

Its working in local workspace as the webservice is creating with local directory structure for wsdl file. 
But after generating war from pom.xml and if i place the war file in server, the webservice is not taking server path instead it is still taking local directory for wsdl.

Can someone tell me how to resolve this.

Comment: What do you even do with `<wsdlUrls>`. This has nothing to do with Spring, nor Spring boot as far as I know. It looks like some part of a Maven plugin configuration, but then again, what does a Maven plugin configuration have anything to do with a WAR file on a server. This question is unclear to me.

Comment: Yes this is a maven plugin, but the maven plugin has generated java sources based on the wsdl like  this   static {
        URL url = null;
        WebServiceException e = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("file:/D:/MyProject/workspace/abc/AbcOpsIntegration/src/main/resources/logging.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) { ...} the path is the problem since i am copying war generated war file to server.

Comment: Ok, but your generated .WAR file should already contain the generated classes, so why does it look for that WSDL file when you run it on your server. EDIT: Noticed that you edited your comment. Where does that code come from? Is that generated? Add it to your question and the Maven configuration necessary to reproduce this. This rather looks like an issue with the plugin rather than with Spring or Spring boot, so I would suggest retagging the question as well. Also, considering that the code you posted uses `logging.wsdl` in stead of `logging_service.wsdl` I doubt they're related.

Comment: yes  you are correct, i was mistaken while editing my comment, both are loggin_service.wsdl only, i understand now i can generate java classes using command line also to aovid this, i can comment the maven plugin and generate source code, let me give a try, Thanks for your suggestions.